# Reconstruct image using inverse DFT and magnitude + phase matrices in OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv, dft

Assuming the official DFT tutorial (using java bindings) https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d01/tutorial_discrete_fourier_transform.html I do the following:

```
    Mat complexI = new Mat();
    Core.merge(planes, complexI);         // Add to the expanded another plane with zeros
    Core.dft(complexI, complexI);         // this way the result may fit in the source matrix
    // compute the magnitude
    Core.split(complexI, planes);
    Mat magI = new Mat();
    Core.magnitude(planes.get(0), planes.get(1), magI);
    Mat phasI = new Mat();
    Core.phase(planes.get(0), planes.get(1), phasI);
    Mat newComplexI = new Mat();
    Core.merge(magI, phasI, newComplexI);
    complexI.get(0,0)[0] == newComplex.get(0,0)[0]; // FALSE
```

What is going on? Just breaking the `complexI` into magnitude and phase matrices and recomposing them produces a different matrix. If I do this test *before* the `Core.dft` call then it works fine. Is it because the `Mat` post-dft has floating point numbers and we lose on precision? The differences between `complexI` and `newComplexI` however are much larger than a phew decimals, sometimes in the thousands.

How can I properly reconstruct the image from the mag and phase matrices using inverse dft?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would have deleted the question but it was upvoted, I guess someone else had the same question.

This makes total sense, I just didn't think the problem enough before asking. The `complexI` is a 2 channel matrix representing the `Re` numbers in the first channel and the `Im` in the second channel. Split essentially gives 2 single-channel matrices with all the `Re` and `Im` numbers respectively. Using the `magnitude` function essentially computes `sqrt(Re^2 + Im^2)` which gives a totally different number from `Re` and `Im`. `phase` is similar but using the phase computation formula. Taking those 2 numbers (mag and phase) and putting them through `merge` simply generates a new 2-channel matrix where `Re` is now the `mag` numbers and `Im` is now the phase numbers, which have nothing to do with the original numbers this the `newComplexI` is totally different, as expected.

In order to achieve what I was looking for, a call to `polarToCart(mag, phase,...)` function to get back the `Re` and `Im` values.